# What's the difference when new operator is applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if I would like to display the current date on the `p` element:

```
$("p").html('Now is '+Date()); // good
$("p").html('Now is '+new Date()); // good
$("p").html(Date()); // good
$("p").html(new Date()); // bad
```

Why the last statement does not display the current date, but the second statement works?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first and third lines `Date()` returns a string of the current date.

In the second one, when you add a Date object to a string it must be converting the date object to a string, so you see what you expect.

In the last line, it returns a date object, which is why it looks wrong.

To read more about `Date` you may find this useful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date

Comment: So, jQuery html() method accepts a string, not a Date object. In order to make the last statement work, we can do:
    $("p").html(new Date().toString()); // good now

Comment: @realguess or `"" + new Date()` -- reason number 2 in the post works for the exact same reason as using `toString()`.

Answer (score 5):

I am only going to take a stab at this:

// Javascript parser detects string concatenation. Date() is converted to string (default).

```
("p").html('Now is '+Date());
```

// Javascript parser detects string concatenation. Date() is converted to string (default).

```
$("p").html('Now is '+new Date());
```

// Instance of date via Date() constructor is converted to string by default.

```
$("p").html(Date());
```

// new Date() produces an object. Inserting a non-dom recognized object into dom tree throws error.

```
$("p").html(new Date());
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, but one correction: the last one doesn't throw an error, but since the argument isn't a string or a function, jQuery simply ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

The answers seem to suggest that you're more interested in string concatenation and the `Date` object. However, the question title suggests you're more concerned with the general behavior of the `new` operator and objects in JavaScript in general. So maybe this answer is completely irrelevant.

But, for what it's worth, the `new` operator is what tells the constructor to return an object. It's a shortcut for constructor constructors. Take the following code:

```
function SomeConstructor(val1, val2) {
    this.val1 = val1;
    this.val2 = val2;
}

var constructed_obj = SomeConstructor('something', 'else');
```

The above code will (if not executed in strict mode) **append values to the global object**. Uh oh.

Also not good:

```
SomeConstructor.prototype = {
    method1: function () { ... },
    method2: function () { ... }
};

var constructed_obj = SomeConstructor();
```

The above `constructed_obj` **will not have access to `method1` or `method2`**. This might not seem like such a big deal, but imagine creating a new `Date` object without having any way of accessing its methods!

tl;dr:
Sans `new`, le déluge.